# Se puede Ordenar imágenes en collectionView, usando un parámetro desde JSON?

Tags: json, swift, swift3, swift4

quiero ordenar una colección de imagenes, la imagen esta en el mismo JSON que el parámetro, pero en diferente llave... este es el JSON..

```
  "data": {
    "1": {
        "NOMBRE": "Almacen Principal",
        "CONFIGURACION": {},
        "IMAGENES": {
            "P_LANDSCAPE": ""
        },
        "CATEGORIAS": { 
            "CUBEXSERV": {
                "NOMBRE": "Cube Xserve",
                "CONFIGURACION": {
                    "ORDEN": 1     <- ESTE ES EL PARAMETRO PARA ORDENAR LA LISTA
                },
                "IMAGENES": {
                    "P_LANDSCAPE": (codigo imagen)... <- ELEMENTO DE LA IMAGEN
```

y después están otros 15 elementos que tienen la misma estructura y se encuentran en la llave "CATEGORIAS", como pueden ver, pues necesito sacar el valor de cada elemento de la llave "ORDEN" para que las imagenes estén ordenadas... 1,2,3,4,5, etc.... cada imagen es colocada en una celda, el collectionView la muestra sin problemas, pero necesito hacer el orden usando ese parámetro ... yo lo que hice primero fue sacar el valor "ORDEN" de cada objeto usando "filter".. ( lo hice de manera nativa.. se que existe alamofire y SwiftyJSON pero quiero hacerlo de forma nativa)
asi saque el valor de cada parámetro "ORDEN"....

una vez tengo la key de "CATEGORIA" usando JSONSerialization...

```
   guard let ordenDicJSON = configDicJSON.value(forKey: "ORDEN") else { return false }

   categoriaJSON.filter { (key, value) -> Bool in 

        categoriasDicJSON = value as! NSDictionary
                configDicJSON = categoriasDicJSON.value(forKey: "CONFIGURACION") as! NSDictionary
                guard let ordenDicJSON = configDicJSON.value(forKey: "ORDEN") else { return false }

                ordenDicValor.append(ordenDicJSON as! Int)

                return true
            }

            if ordenDicValor.count == 0 {
                print("no hay valores en la lista")
            }
            ordenDicValor.sort()
            print(ordenDicValor)
```

y ya me pinta el ordenDicValor [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
y antes estaba pues desordenado.. ejem: [1,5,14,9,12.. ETC]

me gustaría ordenar las imagenes usando los valores ordenados para que se coloquen de manera correcta en el collectionView...

Comment: Podrias intentar usando estructuras decodificables, esto te permitira almacenar tu json en un arreglo el cual seria la data del collectionView, puedes ver un ejemplo de esto aqui: https://youtu.be/YY3bTxgxWss

Comment: si es una muy buena idea y aparte con decode me ahorraría algo de codigo, lo voy a intentar ... gracias por responder